# How can i avoid html entities like &#8211 in JSON API?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, webview, androidx

I'm developing wordpress android app using JSON REST API & retrofit library.
I'm fetching data using JSON API LINK [click here this is link](http://www.marineeto.we.bs/wp-json/wp/v2/posts). I'm facing problem with decoding JSON data in Android Webview. HTML entities like `&#8220` is decoded as `&` post stops loading at this point. I'm facing problem only in android API LEVEL 29 not but in API LEVEL 26. How to fix this issue.[WEBVIEW SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBav0.jpg). If I remove apostrophe, semi-colon, quotes from my post its loading fine.

**example:**

\n\n\n\n

A.</strong> In all electrical equipment is tested by a test voltage which is twice the system voltage plus one.For Example</em>: `&#8211;` If system voltage is `&#8220;`6.6KV`&#8221;` the test voltage will be `&#8220;`2 X 6.6 + 1`&#8221;`</strong> in KV, i.e., `&#8220;`14.2KV`&#8221;` approximately say `&#8220;`15KV`&#8221;`.</p>\n\n\n\n

If there is an Inductive or Capacitive fault the `&#8220;`transient surge voltage`&#8221;` occurs which is 4 times system voltage to earth. So for 6.6KV system surge voltage becomes `&#8220;`4 X 6.6KV = 26.4KV`&#8221;`</strong> if neutral is insulated.</p>\n\n\n\n